# Is this sentence from »Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung« correct?

Tags: passive, future

The below paragraph appears in the article “[So plant die Deutsche Bank die Zukunft des Investment-Bankings](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/unternehmen/deutsche-bank-besetzt-schluesselposten-15587881.html)” from *Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung*:

> Die Deutsche Bank hat die zweite Führungsebene im Investmentbanking neu besetzt. *Wie aus einer der F.A.Z. vorliegenden internen Mitteilung hervorgeht, **werden** den Bereich unterhalb des Vorstands Ram Nayak und Mark Fedorcik im Range von Ko-Präsidenten **leiten**.* Sie werden beide an Garth Ritchie berichten, der im Vorstand die Unternehmens- und Investmentbank verantwortet. Der Südafrikaner kündigte in der internen Mitteilung an, die Kosten noch schneller zu senken als bisher geplant.

My question refers to the second sentence of the above paragraph: Should not *werden* be *wird* and *leiten* be *geleitet*?

Comment: FAZ ist a bad place for looking for syntax errors. ***Sie*** (plural!) ***werden*** (plural!) *leiten*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is correct as can be seen by crunching the sentence down to easier parts:

> - Hans und Eva leiten den Bereich. *Present tense*
> - Eva wird den Bereich leiten. *Future tense singular*
> - Hans und Eva **werden** den Bereich **leiten**. *Future tense plural*
> - Wie mitgeteilt werden Hans und Eva den Bereich leiten. *Only word order was changed*
> - Wie mitgeteilt, werden den Bereich Hans und Eva leiten. *Quote and a bit unusual but correct word order*

---

Addendum from issue in comment:

The sentence part *unterhalb des Vorstands* further specifies the accusative object *Bereich*. So it is not Ram and Mark who are part of the management board (*Vorstand*) but they are one level below (*unterhalb*):

> - Hans und Eva leiten den Bereich unterhalb des Vorstands.

Comment: If it were not for the words "unterhalb des" in the original sentence, I would agree with your explanation. The sentence could have read without "unterhalb des" like this: "Wie mitgeteilt, werden den Bereich Vorstände Ram Nayak und Mark Fedorcik im Range von Ko-Präsidenten leiten." But with "unterhalb des" the sentence seems to be in the passive voice. My rough English translation of the INTENDED VERSION of the ORIGINAL sentence: "... the department will be run by board members Ram Nayak und Mark Fedorcik, officiating as co-presidents". Continued below:

Comment: But your examples are in the active voice: "Hans and Eva will lead the department." They (your example sentences) seem to ignore "unterhalb des", which make the original sentence passive.

Comment: @EugeneStr.: see edit - there is no passive voice here, it is future tense of [leiten](http://www.canoo.net/inflection/leiten:V:haben)